# Typescript Use compiler option '--downlevelIteration' to allow iterating of iterators error when attempting to spread

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

I have a function which has an argument of type object or an array.

```
const handleScenarioChange = (scenario: Scenario | Scenario[]) => {
  if (isArray(scenario)) {
    const scenarios = [...state.selectedScenarios, ...scenario];
    const uniqueScenarios = removeDuplicateScenarios(scenarios);
    setState({ selectedScenarios: sortBy(uniqueScenarios, ['Name']) });
  } else {
    // If scenario is not an array, that means this is adding tag
    const scenarios = [...state.selectedScenarios, scenario];
    const uniqueScenarios = removeDuplicateScenarios(scenarios);
    setState({ selectedScenarios: sortBy(uniqueScenarios, ['Name']) });
  }
};
```

As you can see, I am creating uniqueScenarios and setting the state again in an if and else block. However, I want to use a ternary operator to do the same.

I tried

```
    const scenarios = [...state.selectedScenarios, ...(isArray(scenario)) ? ...scenario : scenario];
    const uniqueScenarios = removeDuplicateScenarios(scenarios);
    setState({ selectedScenarios: sortBy(uniqueScenarios, ['Name']) });
```

My compilerOptions.target in my tsconfig.json is es5. I changed it to es6 and still doesnt work. Please advice.

Stackblitz link: [URL](https://www.staging-typescript.org/play?skipLibCheck=true&allowJs=true&target=1&module=5#code/FAUwHgDg9gTgLgAhAOwK4FsEFUDOIYBKUANiAgN7AIIDCxAlinAPoEgCGAJswOoz1wQzXPgQBeBACYANFVoMmrDtwDyyYgE9heGOIQBmWQF9goSLET1kgmADN2AYzIjdlavU4AuBGnQAjfABuOQARehwIYnYtADl2dBBvHDh%20ZABzYOoXZjiEpJSrDLkiUm8XEpBM%20UZrAEkQ718A3QAfH1RiYmCTOXBoeAQ4DQhnHTCIqI1a5FsoPQAFegcAawAeF2kEAHJxyOic%20JAthDat7NyjgD5guV7zAZQMBABlJ2R2figAUU4BZ7h2IIKHIADJQFYgTh6AAMsmoKgA7sh8D8BHoAIybAD0WIQABUABbhBA4AlQDpQgIIBzsTqQhAAIjxqQEGmwOgQsAQAFkoJwQMQEIjkTAGXIeLBiJxUYgJDJgD0%20hYkL4Xm8PvQoABBGAOIkANxAADEomlgdQaKgYDAmDC4QgdXr6IaoRJMQrbu5rPh7E41SgNXM3AgLvlUkVqABNDgwRoYZpVR0GoQm9hpbyvAOfJPO42mqoy5j-QGJf3vT4y4uCKq8-nEabJdjIJz1OP%20IJyDxthNyBw2kvcQFhwpVPscQTcPwabsd6hjgfMKfMLvtdswKqoCCcBdDkkFdIbrcLqcAfjKY3CeymMygh%203E8XWg8Z9XPeoYJWz1QfnQ4RwmuQVtX1nBA6xAB9d2ScMTnaToqk4DR3l-BxmBwb9fxwf8oGQHAZxgABtABdKo0J-P8ANw4CCOIj1gAcbDkhJAUQAcCdM3LTVKPYwMiL0fC5Goahg2oBkc0NZhUzSBlvFhATGULKsQGkqR7REj9li-MjMIA%20plP0SQABYAA5VMZWsBQbAFmxAXTvH0ABOAA2UyGQuZSGQAIXYPBaG8sgaCgCANAZFzow%20ZTJGhSKXPnCC4HcyLIoAWmhfQUoMvFIs8Az9E8fR0QAOkkIyAHZoXKgBqcrPHKkK5IZWLIUfZSAFYYv7B8lw8VqXLAuLlLQTpesQ%20IllQ9DyIY5T%20MEwT9IMtq5OoeajLkwiXO67x0Ra%20yTPq0iMKwnDpqWgxDMW2blsM1bZvW%20rN3vJrAQSqLoRStLoQyrKWvRTwWskAr0UcsrKuq2qXIe49gu8YTBIZXZJgOBJ3PYPwHDqy7GXOQ4UbRgr6PQMVZqMCGj06p9OGU9EboQEm5Fh0TdWTCTTWU2TZoZBSAUECKXPUzTDp0kI9P0aE9o58z6xwqyW2FuynJctzvCZSQMbhsLRW8RL2bhxrB3i5XtfepL0Qy6rDJqgGWsc8rQehGroTVkS9ea7wLt1jqmq6ym3d65j%20rjIb6oQpCxoOybju8GbLv0UWaeoO6Oc2hAgf0EqXPD7Spqj07Y7FtbSce-WXuS1KTbN%202Laigrrdt6Eqvt8H7rJr3ofNS74cvRGlcZVH0dMkTseR5W%20-xqBCbkumOch8nlx9hAWrkOnCM9akGMQAkm04UhuM%20GhN-SMgJAAChwdVPgzc-NRg3fNSIgBKcRLnb6gcQQehbAQY-wh1GBolPq%20UB76P1hm-Oc68SSAJwHxAqsDGyCAKngUgrFIS3ygDgTYsDEGAJorNMBCAbRwCtMgSBWZOJyTfkYJAxAfKgNxK-XEtRP5nzIXMYkyAoCICbAgD4f8NCbDgJvRACQmzQMEcSYkXBfjpEGGmCh9C17S1IRxdBMC4HcxAIg5iKDOBoIwcowMuDBL4MIcQgxnwcDyNpqdeiSiWEqOgRIfCWCkEsTYlAzBsDj6-2iAVH%201p-72MDMAhAJ4EAuMAQgJIOCqizVMTAEhQSLFL0CEAA)

Comment: I don't think you should be getting errors with that. Can you put a link to a minimal example the is raising the error on a [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html)?

Comment: @AlexWayne Updated OP

Answer (score 0):

Your first snippet should work without error, but your second snippet has invalid syntax:

```
const scenarios = [
  ...state.selectedScenarios,
  ...(isArray(scenario)) ? ...scenario : scenario
];
```

You have too many `...` spreads here. The spread with parens will spread an array that is the value of the expression in the parens. That means that the parens *must* resolve to an array.

```
[...(expression().thatReturns().anArray)]
```

So to make that ternary work, you need to make sure it always returns an array by either returning the original array, or by wrapping the single item case in an array:

```
  const scenarios = [
    ...selectedScenarios,
    ...(Array.isArray(scenario) ? scenario : [scenario])
  ];
```